# How to get HAVP(HTTP Anti Virus Proxy) working?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, antivirus

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server with HAVP(HTTP Anti Virus Proxy) with ClamAV and AVG. My dhcp server is a OpenBSD 5.2 router.

If I connect manually to my Ubuntu server its works great, but when I'm setting the router to forward the HTTP traffic to the Ubuntu server its not working.

I could see in the tcpdump that the traffic from the router is redirected to the Ubuntu server.

```
01:12:34.562253 IP 192.168.1.14.64642 > 192.168.1.11.http-alt: Flags [R], seq 1739163894, win 0, length 0

01:12:34.562164 IP 192.168.1.11.http-alt > 192.168.1.14.64642: Flags [S.], seq 3267364044, ack 1739163894, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

Where `192.168.1.14` is my client PC, and `192.168.1.11` is the Ubuntu server.

Any suggestions for how to get this working?
i want to get the havp server to accept redirected traffic